# Asymptotic behavior of a set of nonnegative integers whose sumset with itself is the nonnegative integers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sumset

Let $S$ be a set of nonnegative integers such that the sumset $S+S$ is the nonnegative integers. If it can, what is the fastest growing function $f$ such that the number of elements of $S$ less than $n$ is proportional to $n/f(n)?$

$S$ can have zero natural density, with an example being the numbers that are sums of two nonnegative integer squares, but it has $f = \sqrt{\log {n}},$ so it looks suboptimal to me.

Comment: Maybe try something like the union of all the natural numbers with $0$ in the even entries and the natural numbers with $0$ in the odd entries (so, sticking to binary, $S$ contains numbers like $101010101$ and $100000$.).  Clearly every natural number is a sum of two elements in $S$.

Comment: The question is: what is its asymptotic density?

Comment: It is asymptotic to $\sqrt{n}.$ Solved.